# Preventing CSRF with a cross-domain JavaScript call

Tags: javascript, json, jsonp, csrf

I'd like to protect my site against [cross-site request forgery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery). I'm trying to follow [these recommendations](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#General_Recommendation%3a_Synchronizer_Token_Pattern), by sending a session-specific token along with all requests that need to be protected.

The catch is that I have some requests that are designed to be called by third-party sites, on a different domain. Most of them use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP): they make a request to our server using a `<script>` tag, and the response is JavaScript code that calls a function on their page.

My question is, how to I pass the token in these requests? It seems like the third-party site would need to know the token. I could provide another request that returns the token as JSON, but then untrusted sites could make the same request, get the token, and use it to forge requests to our server.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Is anything actually done when they request the JS? Is there any *reason* you would need to protect the script?

Comment: Yes, some of the scripts perform operations that I don't want unauthorized sites to be able to perform.

Comment: My understanding is that JSONP basically operates via GET requests, but that one of the first steps in preventing CSRF is to only use POST.

Comment: I don't think that would prevent CSRF. You could make a form that auto-submits to my script's URL using POST.

Comment: Right, that's not *everything*, but it's [a good beginning](http://shiflett.org/articles/cross-site-request-forgeries).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XSRF tokens are usually cookies on your domain that you generate.  You really don't want to introduce a mechanism to allow other sites to set those.  Verifying that a message comes from a trusted party is better treated as a signature verification problem.

You can have each partner site generate and keep a private/public [signature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature) key pair.  Then they can send you their public key.

They can then sign their messages to you.

So their request would look like

```
 <script src="https://.../yourservice?partnerid=foobar&signedquerystring"></script>
```

and then you can signature check that the signed query string was properly signed using the public key you looked up by the key `foobar`.

You now know to trust the request if it either has your XSRF token or it is properly signed using the private key of a partner you've established a relationship with.

This won't stop someone who can observe a logged in user viewing the partner site from replaying the request, so the partner site and your script should both be loaded via a secure channel (`https`), just as you would with multiple-use XSRF tokens.

Comment: this does increase the difficulty though and requires server-side processing, defeating many of the advantages of using JSONP in the first place.

Comment: @PhillipWhelan, XSRF protection is all about prevent abuse of same-origin privileges.  That can't be done unless a server is involved in mediating what gets run in its origin, so yes, JSONP that can exercise abusable authority requires a server round trip.  The only alternative is to have client side code (served from that origin but cacheable) check content that is fetched cross origin and preserve any security properties.  `<script>` tags can't be used for that kind of fetch-and-verify-before-executing though.  EcmaScript.next's module loader will solve this problem though.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem that I am using is to embed an IFRAME inside the UI of an external widget I am creating. The only drawback here is the possibility of others using this iframe in a clickjacking attack. You could read about that here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/13341/security-issues-using-iframes.

Answer (score 0):

I have the simplest solution to the JSONP CSRF problem, Add the "While(1);" or "for(,,);" or throw "F*** U"; in start of your json response data.

Now Any JSONP request end up in a infinite loop. Because you aren’t using a JSONP request, you have the ability to modify the response by this code

```
JSON.parse(this.responseText.slice("while(1);".length));
```